# vue-auth - Redirection after login to inital request

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using the last version of `vue-js` and `vue-auth` whose documentation could be find [here](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth)

By default `vue-auth` would redirect the user to `/login` if `auth` is true and if the user is not logged in.

So if I type `http://example.com/mycomponent` I will be redirect to `/login`.

#### Issue

After being loged, I'm redirect to `/`

#### Questions

What can I do so after being logged one is redirected to his initial request ?

If I type `/mycomponent` I'd like to be redirect to `/mycomponent` after login

#### Routes

```
{
      path: '/mycomponent',
      name: 'mycomponent',
      component: mycomponent,
      meta: { auth: true }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on the [documentation](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth/blob/master/docs/Methods.md#redirect), you can call `this.$auth.redirect();` on your login method to detect if the user was redirected to the login page.

You can then add the redirect option with a path.

```js
var redirectObj = this.$auth.redirect();

this.$auth.login({
   redirect: {
        path: redirectObj ? redirectObj.from.path : '/'
    },
});
```

You can also use a [named route](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-routes.html) instead of the path.

```js
this.$auth.login({
    redirect: {
        name: redirectObj ? redirectObj.from.name : 'default-named-route'
    },
});
```